# when hover on a card in row other cards get closer 1 px to it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row that contains 4 cards,

I want to remove the border and set a box shadow when hovering on a card with transition

my problem is when hovering on a card the other cards get closer to it `1px`

for example, go and hover the second card from the left
the third and the fourth will go to the left 1px, try it on the full page you will understand

if I remove the border it will be fine, so I tried to remove the border in different ways like make it `transparent` or set the color to `#ffffff00` but nothing changed

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ece7e7;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.2);
  border: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem !important;
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #E0E1E3;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.49, 0, 0.98);
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

sorry for the bad English, English is not my native language

Comment: You're toggling borders on and off with hover/unhover, which causes layout jittering.

Answer (score 1):

You reset the border-width by doing `border: rgb(255, 255, 255);` and this causes changing the width. Use `border-color` property instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ece7e7;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.2);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem !important;
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #E0E1E3;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.49, 0, 0.98);
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```